# Google Apps Script mailApp.sendEmail Not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I receive the following Error in my script when trying to use mailApp.sendEmail:

[17-02-01 13:51:13:522 PST] Execution failed: Failed to send email to *******@eicc.edu,******@eicc.edu,*******@eicc.edu (line 115, file "Code") [7.642 seconds total runtime]

I just masked the beginning of the email address for privacy.  The part I don't like is that it says it just "Failed to send email" without any other explanation.  Has anyone else run into this one?

Comment: We would need to see the code where the values passed are defined and also where send email is called.  Can you add that to your post?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer this morning.  The account we were using to authorize the triggers had a "Domain Email" only setup.  The code itself worked.  Thank you for your help.